Having issue with mobile collapsible menu with window.onclick function
I have been working on the header section for my project. In the desktop version, I want to click the Resource word in the header and the dropdown menu will appear with resources/sub-menu items, and if the user clicks any place on the page that includes the dropdown menu it collapses. For that I used
window.onclick = (e) => {
      if (headerRef.current.contains(e.target) === false) {
        setShowResources(false);
      }
    };

Now I am facing an issue when trying to build a mobile menu.

The desktop menu should remain the same; if the user clicks anywhere on the page, the menu should close.
I want the same functionality for the mobile menu but inside the mobile menu,[![enter image description here][1]][1] I want to add collapsible functionality which should work when the user clicks on the mobile submenu heading. Please check my code snippet and help me to fix the issue.
Here is my submenu Array:

    const subMenuItems = [
          {
            imgSrc: "home",
            altText: '',
            heading: 'Home',
            links: [
              { to: 'https://home', text: 'Getting Started', description: 'Welcome to the website' }
            ]
          },
          ];
        
    
    
        const SubMenuItem = ({ imgSrc, altText, heading, links }) => {
          const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
        
          const toggleOpen = () => {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
            console.log(!isOpen)
          };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 className="sub-menu-h" onMouseEnter={toggleOpen} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
            <img src={imgSrc} alt={altText} />
            {heading}
            {isOpen ? <ArrowDropUpIcon style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} /> : <ArrowDropDownIcon style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} />}
          </h2>
          {isOpen && (
            <div className="submenu-links">
              {links.map((link, index) => (
                <Link key={index} to={link.to}>
                  {link.text} <p>{link.description}</p>
                  
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
    
          
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    function Header() {
    
      const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(window.innerWidth <= 767);
      const [showResources, setShowResources] = useState(false);
      const headerRef = useRef(null);
      let location = useLocation();
      useEffect(() => {
        window.onscroll = () => {
          if (window.scrollY > 100) {
            headerRef.current.classList.add("scrolled");
          } else {
            headerRef.current.classList.remove("scrolled");
          }
        };
        window.onclick = (e) => {
          if (headerRef.current.contains(e.target) === false) {
            setShowResources(false);
          }
        };
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
          setIsMobile(window.innerWidth <= 767);
        };
    
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    
        // Cleanup the event listener on component unmount
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
      }, []);
    
      const handleOpenResources = () => {
        setShowResources(!showResources);
      };
    
     
      return (
        <>
          <div className="site_header" ref={headerRef}>
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="header_wrapper">
                <Link className="site_logo" to={"/"}>
                  <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
                </Link>
                <div>
                  <div className={`resource_link`} onClick={handleOpenResources}>
                    RESOURCES
                    {showResources ? (
                      <span>
                        <ArrowDropUpIcon />
                      </span>
                    ) : (
                      <span>
                        <ArrowDropDownIcon />
                      </span>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {isMobile ? (
            <MobileDesign showResources={showResources} subMenuItems={subMenuItems} />
          ) : (
            <DesktopDesign showResources={showResources} />
          )}
    
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default Header;
    
    
    const MobileDesign = ({ showResources, subMenuItems }) => (
      <div>
        {showResources && (
          <div className="resources">
            <div className="sub-menu">
              {subMenuItems.map((item, index) => (
                <SubMenuItem key={index} {...item} />
              ))}
            </div>
            
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
    
    const DesktopDesign = ({ showResources }) => (
      <div>
        {showResources && (
          <div className="resources">
            <div className="sub-menu">
              DESKTOP MENU 
               <Link to="/about">
                About Us <p>Learn about our company </p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/9nu0TW2K.png


Solved by using separate ref for desktop and mobile    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {       if (         headerRef.current.contains(e.target) === false &&         (isMobile           ? mobileMenuRef.current && mobileMenuRef.current.contains(e.target) === false           : desktopMenuRef.current && desktopMenuRef.current.contains(e.target) === false)       ) {         setShowResources(false);       }     };
